# How to change field cardinality per form either programatically or by rule?

Tags: 7, entities, rules

I've a multipage form (where each page is determined by field group) where on the first page user type number of people in text field and on the second one I would like to show X number of field collection instances based on the given number. So if user selects 5 people, I expect to see 5 field collection placeholders to fill for the user and no more *Add another item* buttons (especially when field cardinality is set to Unlimited).

Is there any solution which can achieve setting up cardinality per form state by a rule or from the code?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are the following hooks which allow to alter the widget form such as [`hook_field_widget_form_alter`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21field%21field.api.php/function/hook_field_widget_form_alter/7) and [`hook_field_widget_WIDGET_TYPE_form_alter`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21field%21field.api.php/function/hook_field_widget_WIDGET_TYPE_form_alter/7), but they only apply to widget form element.

As for workaround, it's possible to set the field to Unlimited and use [`hook_form_alter`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21Form%21form.api.php/function/hook_form_alter/8) to remove add_more element manually like:

```
$form[$field_name][LANGUAGE_NONE][0]['remove_button']['#access'] = FALSE;
$form[$field_name][LANGUAGE_NONE]['add_more']['#access'] = FALSE;
```

or overriding/removing `#theme`:

```
unset($form['field_foo'][LANGUAGE_NONE][0]['#theme']);
```

for certain conditions.

---

Using Rules, it's possible to use [Rules Forms Support](https://www.drupal.org/project/rules_forms) module which can deal with form elements, so you can change the `items_count`. Here is sample rule dealing with a multi value field in [Entityform](https://www.drupal.org/project/entityform):

```
/**
 * Implements hook_action_info().
 */
function mymodule_entityform_rules_rules_action_info() {
  return array(
    'foo_entityform_rules_set_cardinality_value' => array(
      'label' => t('Change items count of a multi value field'),
      'group' => t('Rules Forms'),
      'parameter' => array(
        'form' => array('type' => 'form', 'label' => t('Form')),
        'form_state' => array('type' => 'form_state', 'label' => t('Form State')),
        'element' => array('type' => 'form_element', 'label' => t('Target Element')),
        'value' => array('type' => 'form_element', 'label' => t('Value from Element')),
      ),
      'base' => 'foo_entityform_rules_set_cardinality_value',
      'callbacks' => array(
        'access' => 'rules_forms_integration_access',
        'form_alter' => 'rules_forms_element_form_alter',
      ),
    ),
  );
}

/**
 * Implementation of rule callback.
 */
function mymodule_entityform_rules_set_cardinality_value($form, $form_state, $element, $value) {
  module_load_include("module", "rules_forms", 'rules_forms');
  $val_elem = &_rules_forms_get_element($form, $value);
  if (!isset($form_state['field'])) {
    return;
  }

  $element = substr($element, strpos($element, ':') + 1);
  $path = explode(':', $element);
  if (count($path) == 1) {
    $path[] = LANGUAGE_NONE;
  }

  $field_state = &drupal_array_get_nested_value($form_state['field'], $path);
  if (!$field_state) {
    return;
  }

  $limit = !empty($val_elem['#value']) ? $val_elem['#value'] : (!empty($val_elem['#default_value']) ? $val_elem['#default_value'] : NULL);
  $field_state['items_count'] = $limit;
  $field_state['field']['cardinality'] = $limit; // Won't work for field_multiple_value_form().
}
```

This works when field is set to Unlimited, however *Add another* and *Remove* buttons still needs to be removed from `form_alter` as shown below:

```
/**
 * Implements hook_form_alter().
 */
function mymodule_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id) {

    // Check cardinality.
    // If items_count for a field has reach its cardinality limit,
    // then remove Add more and Remove buttons.
    foreach ($form as $key => $item) {
      if (is_array($item) && !empty($item['#type']) && !empty($item['#language']) && $item['#type'] == 'container') {
        $field = &$form[$key];
        $langcode = $field['#language'] ?: LANGUAGE_NONE;
        $field_state = field_form_get_state($field[$langcode]['#field_parents'], $field[$langcode]['#field_name'], $langcode, $form_state);
        if ($field_state['items_count'] == $field_state['field']['cardinality']) {
          $field[$langcode]['add_more']['#access'] = FALSE;
          foreach (array_column($field[$langcode], 'remove_button') as $key2 => $rm_item) {
            $field[$langcode][$key2]['remove_button']['#access'] = FALSE;
          }
        }
      }
    } // end: foreach
  }
}
```

---

It's also worth to try some patches from [Allow cardinality to be restricted (overridden and reduced) in the field instance settings](https://www.drupal.org/node/1029298) or  [Add hook alter to override field_multiple_value_form()](https://www.drupal.org/node/1592814).

There is also [Field instance cardinality](https://www.drupal.org/project/field_instance_cardinality) module which allows the cardinality of specific instances of fields to be overridden.

Some other proposed workaround from [here](https://www.drupal.org/node/1029298) by [@donquixote](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/users/2974/donquixote) (without actually hacking Drupal core) could include:

- [a new widget type with `FIELD_BEHAVIOR_CUSTOM`](https://www.drupal.org/node/1029298#comment-10672988) with widget settings to change a cardinality limit, the name of another ("decorated") field widget type and other settings for the decorated field widget type,
- [add a number field in the instance settings form](https://www.drupal.org/node/1029298#comment-10673042) and use `hook_field_widget_properties_alter` to replace `$instance['widget']['module']` (keep original in `$instance['widget']['_module']`) and replace `override $instance['widget']['type']` with own `FIELD_BEHAVIOR_CUSTOM` and save the original in `$instance['widget']['_type']`, so you can do the same decorator trick in `hook_field_widget_form` as above.

---

#### Modules

Related modules:

- [Multivalue Extras](https://www.drupal.org/project/multivalue_extras)

  > Enhances settings for multiple value fields.

Answer (score 0):

Another approach suggested by [@BDuell](https://www.drupal.org/u/bduell) in his [post](https://www.drupal.org/node/1337804#comment-11185315):

```
  // In your hook_form_FORM_ID_alter() function...

  // Our field and the number of values that we need to have in it...
  $field_name = 'field_machine_name';
  $items_count = count($array_of_values);

  // If we have an array of values that need to be prepopulated...
  if (!empty($array_of_values) && $form_state['field'][$field_name][LANGUAGE_NONE]['items_count']!=$items_count) {
    $form_state['field'][$field_name][LANGUAGE_NONE]['items_count'] = $items_count;
    $form_theme = $form[$field_name][LANGUAGE_NONE]['#theme'];
    $items = &$form_state['field'][$field_name][LANGUAGE_NONE];
    // Generate required number of fields collection
    if ($items_count > 1 and $items['items_count'] != $items_count) {
      $items['items_count'] = $items_count;
      $items['field']['cardinality'] = $items_count;
      $form[$field_name][LANGUAGE_NONE] = field_multiple_value_form($items['field'], $items['instance'], LANGUAGE_NONE, array(), $form, $form_state);
      // Reset theme function, as field_multiple_value_form hijacks it
      $form[$field_name][LANGUAGE_NONE]['#theme'] = $form_theme;
    }

    // Tell our form that we need to rebuild once we are done...
    $rebuild_p = TRUE;
  }

  // ANY OTHER FORM ALTER STUFF

  // If we need to rebuild, notify the form...
  if ($rebuild_p) $form['#after_build'][] = 'MYMODULE_after_build';
```

then in custom module you can define `hook_after_build` like:

```
/**
 * Rebuild the form if necessary...
 */
function MYMODULE_after_build($form, &$form_state) {
  return drupal_rebuild_form($form_state['build_info']['form_id'], $form_state, $form);
}
```