# How do I change cardinality (delta) of nodes?

Tags: 7, hooks

I have a content type, this content type has a Field Collection with cardinality(delta) value 1.

- I want to alter it dynamically, when the node add form is rendered.
- Each node add form has it different cardinality(delta) value.

Please any one help me to solve it in Drupal 7.

Answer (score 0):

You can use form_alter hook to do it:

```
/**
 * Implements hook_form_alter().
 */
function your_module_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id) {
  if ($form_id == 'article_node_form') {
    // Alter your field here:
    // $form['field_collection'][LANGUAGE_NONE][0]['value'];
  }
}
```

To debug form output, you can install [Devel](https://www.drupal.org/project/devel) module and use dpm() function.

```
/**
 * Implements hook_form_alter().
 */
function your_module_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id) {
  dpm($form);
}
```

Comment: yes, but i am unable to change cardinality(delta) value here.

Comment: Then maybe this link can help you: http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/192243/how-to-change-field-cardinality-per-form-either-programatically-or-by-rule